# Unable to View Leads on Contact Object's Related Lead List

Tags: contact, leads, related-list

I have a custom field (Associated_Contact__c) on my lead object to create a relationship to an associated contact (via lookup field).

The field is populating as expected, but when I look at the related object list for leads on the contact, it's empty.
An SOQL query for the contact using the relationship field (Associated_Lead__r) also returns a result for the lead as expected.

What reason could there that the lead is not populating on the related object list? (I suspect something in field level security, but I'm not sure).

Comment: Are you sure the correct Related List is being displayed on the Contact page layout? You may have duplicated Lead related lists.

Comment: Thanks @TSmith! That was it. There were two related lead lists on the contact object (one of which did not display the associated leads).

Do you want to submit your comment as an answer and I'll accept it?

Thanks again : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly a strong cup of coffee and a page layout review might help out here. I have a feeling there are multiple lookups from Lead to Contact and your custom relationship is not visible on the page layout you are viewing ;)